# Creating all necessary files from INTERLIS .ili file to produce and deliver data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-plugins, interlis

I was provided with a INTERLIS 2.3 model as .ili file, and nothing else.

As far as I understand it, I should:

- create a .imd meta file using ili2c.jar or the interlis Import/Export plugin by Pirmin Kalberer, i.e. the "Ili Model -> IlisMeta" tool
- export an XML-file from the meta file (i.e. .xtf or .xml), encapsulating the data structure but no content yet using ili2pg.jar
- import this structure into a postgreSQL / PostGIS database
- create shapefiles (point, line, and polygon) using ogr2ogr.jar, which are (probably) already linked to the PostGIS DB
- create the features (i.e., points, lines, polygons) and
- use QGIS forms to fill the linked database with attributes

I already fail at the first point. Java delivers a `.NullPointerException`, and the plugin doesn't create any output without a warning or an error.

How do I produce the necessary files properly?

I'm completely new to INTERLIS, and might have misunderstood some concepts, but would be happy if someone could point me to the right ressources to get to productive GIS layers from an .ili file. I'm running **QGIS 2.14.8-Essen** (LTR), and the INTERLIS model in question is not (yet) published.

Comment: Since noone comments or answers to this question: I ended up creating three shapefiles (points, lines, polygons) with the attributes as described in the .ili file (but I can't have text fields >255 chars, as specified in the model). I furthermore created and added tables without geometries to populate the attribute table using value relations via foreign keys.

Comment: You should post your _comment_ as an **answer** and accept it :)

Comment: @Joseph, it's a crude workaround, not really an answer. I don't like it, and I already lost data due to the field length problem. But its as far as I got.

Answer (score 1):

Check at https://github.com/claeis/ili2db its a tool to import/export/create db schemas from interlis files to relational databases like postgres.

After import your *.ili model into the PostGIS DB you can use QGIS to edit and fill your DB

Another solution is to use https://github.com/AgenciaImplementacion/projectgenerator
Currently only works for QGIS 2.99 under development!

Comment: Thank you, that looks quite promising!
If anybody tries, please leave comments / a minimal example, so I can accept the answer. (I hope I'll find the time to try this soon, right now I'm struggling with other issues arising from *not* having created a proper PostGIS / SpatiaLite DB and fell back to simple shapefiles. )